# Kendo chart not resizing within Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, kendo-dataviz

Please see [here](http://dashboards.stcenergy.com/AlertsDashboard)

When the browser is resized, the Google Map and the grid are correctly resized.  I want the Google map to always take up 100% of the page height.

I want the grid to take 70% and the chart to take up the rest.

However, the chart is not being resized vertically.  Its as if there is a hard coded height somewhere

This is not the same kind of problem that other people have had where the chart does not resize at all, because if you make the browser wider and narrower the chart does resize horizontally

I call the code below when the window is loaded and when the window is resized

```
 $(window).resize(function() {
            resizeGrid();

            var chart = $("#kendoChart").data("kendoChart");
            //to check the chart exist or not if exist then redraw it..
            if (chart) {
                chart.redraw();
            }

        });
```

Also when the window is loaded

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
            

            var chart = $("#kendoChart").data("kendoChart");
            //to check the chart exist or not if exist then redraw it..
            if (chart) {
                chart.redraw();
            }
}
```

I have tried changing the height of the associated CSS class to varying percentages and nothing changes the height of the chart

As you can see from the markup below, I have no hard coded height here

```
<div id="chartContainer" class="chartContainer" >
                @(Html.Kendo().Chart<IMeterProfileData>()
                      .Name("kendoChart")
                      .PlotArea(plotArea =>
                          plotArea.Margin(0)
                      )
                      .Legend(legend => legend
                          .Visible(false)
                      )
                      .AutoBind(false)
                      .Series(series => { series.Column(model => model.Consumption, categoryExpression: model => model.PeriodDateTime).Name("Consumption"); })
                      .CategoryAxis(axis => axis
                          .Date()
                          .BaseUnit(ChartAxisBaseUnit.Minutes).BaseUnitStep(30)
                          .Labels(label => label.Step(48).Rotation(-90).Format("dd/MM/yyyy"))
                          .Axis.MajorGridLines.Visible = false
                      )
                      .ValueAxis(axis => axis.Numeric()
                          .Labels(labels => labels.Format("{0:N0}"))
                          .Line(line => line.Visible(false))
                          .Title("Consumption kWh")
                      )
                      .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
                          .Visible(true)
                          .Format("{0:N0}")
                      ).ChartArea(area => area.Border(1, "#cdcdcd", ChartDashType.Solid)
                      )    )
            </div>
```

Has anyone ever come across this?

Paul

Comment: Inspector Gadget tells you what you're looking for: `.k-chart, .k-stockchart {
height: 400px;
}` is set in kendo.datawiz.min.css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote [the developers](http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-set-size-and-or-resize-a-kendo-chart#NewPFteDXEyXQeqaCXv4lA),

"The size of the Chart can be set initially either in the configuration or by specifying the size on the parent element. For example:

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
    chartArea: {
        width: 200,
        height: 200
    },
    ....
```

If you wish to change the size dynamically, you should also repaint the Chart by using the refresh or redraw methods after the change."

I'm unsure whether this supports percentage heights, only trying will tell. You'll probably have to calculate the height in JS whenever the page size changes if you want a dynamic page that fits the window.

Comment: I have updated my code snippets to show that I am already calling the refresh method.  As I said in my original question, I dont see how it could be related to the chart not being redrawn because the chart's width is changed already as the browser is resized? I will take a look at your other suggestion but I think that could be a nightmare to code as my controls are all hosted within Twitter Bootstrap

Comment: It's not about the chart not being redrawn, it's about the fact that the height of the chart defaulting to 400 unless another value is specified. It will not auto resize to the div's height.

Comment: Thannks Emil this works now, its not perfect but its a lot better!  Seems like when you maximize the window the relative gap between the bottom of the chart and the bottom of the page is gets bigger which is strange.  I dont think I am allowed to put the code here.  I have accepted this answer but is there no way of me putting the code I used to help others?  Im not sure that its right to answer my own question as I was helped to get the answer.  The fix I did was to get the div that the chart is inside of and set the chart's height to container[0].clientHeight

Comment: Glad I could help, @Paul :) Sure, you can answer your own question with the actual code if you'd like.